# Output perl results into file

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have a perl script that works fine when I run it using perl filename, however when I use the command

```
perl -w logint > logintime.html
```

I get this error

```
Use of uninitialized value $days in multiplication (*) at logint line 5, <LAST> line 3.
```

It repeats this from line 3-47

This is the perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open LAST, "last |";
while (<LAST>) {
    if (($name,$days,$hours,$mins) = /^(\w+).+\((?:(\d+)\+)?(\d+):(\d+)/) {
        $TIMES{$name} += 1440 * $days + 60 * $hours + $mins;
    }
}
foreach (sort keys %TIMES) {
    print "$_ $TIMES{$_}\n";
}
```

This is how I'm attempting to output it.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $HDR > ~/public_html/logintime.html
perl -w logint > logintime.html
echo $FTR >> ~/public_html/logintime.html
```

Comment: Did you try to print $days? Are you getting any output?

Comment: I added     print "$days\n"; and it ran fine while using perl logint command, however when I try running perl -w logint > logintime.html it stil had the same error

Comment: You should be looking for the place where the variable `$days` got the assignment. In this case `<LAST> line 3`.

Comment: Is there another way to output the perl results to a file? I was guessing that's what is going wrong.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I only want it to store what it outputs from     print "$_ $TIMES{$_}\n"; into the html file

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: "Use of uninitialized..." is a warning, not error.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with outputting to file. Something else must be broken. Try running `perl -w logint` and see if right output is printed on screen.

Comment: Oh wow I'm silly -w makes it show the warnings. I just looked up how to output a perl script using bash, and added that to my code. I just assumed that -w was needed to output to a file, and didn't look up what w did in the man pages. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` (in preference to `-w` on the command line) at the top of *every* Perl program, and *fix* all the messages you get.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning, it's not an error. You're seeing it when you run that command because '-w' is the warnings pragma.

You could also put it at the end of your shebang

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

Or 'use warnings;'. Anyway, the warning is just saying it doesn't have a value. It looks like you're reading the last log to see who last logged in, the output can be different depending on what OS you're on. I would confirm it's working as expected and getting the correct values.

It's also best practice to use 'use strict;'.